# Why my Maximum Likelihood Estimator of Pareto distribution compute fail, what's wrong whit it?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I've got the density function of Pareto distribution in Wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Parameter_estimation
$$
p(x)=\left\{{\begin{matrix}0,&{\mbox{if }}x<x_{{\min }};\\\\{k\;x_{{\min }}^{k} \over x^{{k+1}}},&{\mbox{if }}x>x_{{\min }}.\end{matrix}}\right.
$$
Let me do some simplification, and we got the new dentisity function and two parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$
$$
f(x)=\left\{{\begin{matrix}0,&{\mbox{if }}x<x_{{\min }};\\\\{\beta  \over x^{{\alpha }}},&{\mbox{if }}x>x_{{\min }}.\end{matrix}}\right.
$$
According to the maximum likelihood estimator theory, we have the liklihood function
$$
{\mathcal {L}}(\alpha,\beta  \,;\,x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n})=f(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots ,x_{n}\mid \alpha,\beta )=\prod _{i=1}^{n}{f(x_{i}\mid \alpha,\beta )}=\frac{\beta^n}{(\prod _{i=1}^{n}{x_i)}^{a}}
$$
and let the derivative of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ equals to $0$

while $x<x_{min}$, $f(x)=0$, this section has no use

while $x>x_{min}$
we got
$$
\frac {\partial \mathcal {L}}{\partial \alpha }=\frac{-\beta^n\sum_{i=1}^{n}{lnx_i} }{(\prod _{i=1}^{n}{x_i})^{a}}=0
$$
$$
\frac {\partial \mathcal {L}}{\partial \beta }=\frac{n\beta^{n-1}}{(\prod _{i=1}^{n}{x_i})^{a}}=0
$$
Solve the equation, we got $\beta =0$

Impossible! What's wrong with it??

Let me change some direction, let
$$
ln{\mathcal {L}}= ln(\frac{\beta^n}{(\prod _{i=1}^{n}{x_i)}^{a}} )=nln\beta+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{ln\frac{1}{x_i^a}} =nln\beta -\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{n}{lnx_i}
$$
and let the derivative = $0$, we got
$$
\frac {\partial ln\mathcal {L}}{\partial \alpha }=-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{lnx_i}=0
$$
$$
\frac {\partial ln\mathcal {L}}{\partial \beta }=\frac{n}{\beta}=0
$$
Solve the equation, we got $\beta =\infty$?
Also impossible!

What's wrong with my compute, please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: This is the case when the maximum point and zero derivatives point are not the same. Also, the likelihood is a bit incorrect, should be $\beta^n$ instead of $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i'll check it again. And also the $\beta$ problem, your eyes are sharp!

Comment: Look at Wikipedia on 'Pareto Distribution' where MLEs $\hat x_{min}=\min_i X_i$ and $\hat \alpha = n[\sum_i(\ln X_i - \ln \hat x_{min})]^{-1}$ are derived (in that order).